# How to export in-line html Java script to .Js File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm new to chrome extensions and after searching around, I'm aware that in line scripts aren't an option. .. That is, I have to use javascript in a seperate file. My question is, how do I create that file? Do I just make a file.js with the < script > copied and pasted and reference it in the html?
Can anyone show me an example of this?
very much appreciated.

> ```
> function changeImage() {
>     var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
>     if (image.src.match("http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif")) {
>         image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif";
>     } else {
>         image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif";
>     } }
> ```

Comment: yes. Just look at any webpage

Comment: Just import your js file at the bottom of page by using `<script src="Pathtoyourfile"></script>`